# How to integrate $ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a-b\cos{x}-c\sin{x}}}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am trying to find a suitable way to perform the following integration, that can be used going forward. The integral is as follows:$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a-b\cos{x}-c\sin{x}}}dx $$

I understand one maybe could you a form of complex/contour integration, could something like that be used here ad does introducing the limits of $2\pi$ and $0$, simplify the problem at all

Answer (score 4):

First, we simplify the denominator

$$\sqrt{a-b\cos{x}-c\sin{x}}=\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\cos(x-\phi)}$$

where, $\cos\phi=\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}, \sin\phi=\frac{c}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}$

Define: $r=\frac{1}a\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$, we get

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\cos(x-\phi)}&=\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{1+r\cos(x-\phi+\pi)}\\
\\
&=\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{1+r-2r\sin^2\left(\frac{x-\phi+\pi}2\right)}\\
\\
&=\sqrt{a(1+r)}\cdot\sqrt{1-\frac{2r}{1+r}\sin^2\left(\frac{x-\phi+\pi}2\right)}\end{align}$$

Let $\displaystyle k^2=\frac{2r}{1+r}$ and $\displaystyle\theta=\frac{x-\phi+\pi}2$, we get the elliptical integral of the first kind:

$$I=\frac{2}{\sqrt {a(1+r)}}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}} d\theta$$